# Rotating in coordination system from 180 to -180

Tags: python, rotation

I am thinking about the simplest way of rotating an object in coordination system which looks like this:

```
       0

-90         90

   -180/180
```

I need to rotate an object until it reaches a given angle. It has to support rotation in both directions. I receive information about the object's current rotation. I have to create a while loop condition when it should stop rotating. It cannot be simple equality statement as the information I receive is not that precise.

EDIT:
The object is a drone which sends me data about its current rotation along z-axis. I rotate it by sending a request to rotate in a given direction. Based on information about its current rotation and the angle by which I want him to rotate (plus the direction of rotation), I need to set up a condition when it should stop rotating and send an apropriate requst.

Comment: What exactly is your question? There are a lot of ways to do this using trig, including simply applying a transformation matrix to any points that define your object. Are you stuck on the math or just the implementation?

Comment: @CoryKramer I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you would need to have another variable that took the direction of rotation (clockwise or anti-clockwise). If the direction was clockwise, you would have angles assigned 0, 90, 180, 270 in clockwise direction. Same for anticlockwise.

Your while loop would be for `angle` < `given angle`, since with the variables being assigned values based on the direction of rotation you wouldn't have to worry about +/- values for the angles.

This is probably a really basic answer and not what you were hoping for, but I hope it helped a little!